# How to find credible interval for multiple bayesian distributions that disagree?

Tags: probability, bayesian, confidence-interval, fitting, credible-interval

Feel free to suggest changes to my terminology here, I don't think this is proper Bayesian analysis.

I'm a scientist trying to produce a credible interval for an unknown experimental value X. The experiments allow me to ask the question:

`P( X | experiment )`

I get this value by looking at the p-value of a binomial function at every value of X and asking: "How likely is it that I could get this data if X == X<sub>0</sub>". (So my P distribution doesn't sum to 1 but rather maxes out at 1.)

By combining multiple experiments together, I arrive at the following representation of my problem:

`P( X | all_data ) = P( X | experiment1 ) * P( X | experiment2 ) ...`

Here are the P(X) traces for a single parameter estimation:
[image: Data where max( P(X) ) == 1 and fitting makes sense.]
Let's say I'm trying to produce a 95% credible interval. I have two different methods that produce satisfactory results here:

1. Normalize the graph such that `sum( P( X | all_data ) ) == 1`. Produce a cumulative distribution. And select `cumul( X_lb ) == 0.025` and `cumul( X_ub ) == 0.975`
2. Simply pick X_lb and X_ub where the graph crosses 0.025.

My problem comes from estimating the bounds when the experiments do not agree with each other. Consider the following experimental traces where the `P( X | all_data )` maxes out at 1e-60:
[image: Data where max( P(X) ) == -60 and the fitting does not make sense.]
Since the `P( X | all_data )` is very sharp here, my credible interval estimations produce very narrow intervals. But this is exactly the opposite of what should happen! My data isn't self-consistent, and so my interval should be huge!

I would like to know the proper way to produce these intervals. For the purposes here, just assume the data is what it is and that I have to produce an upper and lower bound. Normalization is fine, but my traces will always come from p-values of a binomial.